# Rshiny: Narrow Input Panel, Widen Plots

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

I created this sample application with almost the exact format that I would like.  However, when I make the sidebarPanel narrower using the width parameter, the result is that there is simply empty space to the right side of the screen so that the plots are not any wider.  Anybody know how to solve this?  I would like the plots to stretch over the whole screen while keeping the sidebarPanel narrow.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

# Create sample data
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2022-01-01"), by = "day", length.out = 365),
                 value_A = rnorm(365, 50, 10),
                 value_B = rnorm(365, 75, 15),
                 value_C = rnorm(365, 100, 20))

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Sample Line Charts"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("date_range", "Date Range:",
                  min = min(df$date), max = max(df$date),
                  value = c(min(df$date), max(df$date))),
      width = 2
    ),
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(6, plotOutput("plot_A", height = "400px")),
        column(6, plotOutput("plot_B", height = "400px"))
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(12, plotOutput("plot_C", height = "600px"))
      )
    )
  )
)

# Define server
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot_A <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = value_A)) + geom_line()
  })
  
  output$plot_B <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = value_B)) + geom_line()
  })
  
  output$plot_C <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = value_C)) + geom_line()
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could do something like this:

Here we use a grey background CSS for the sidebar. But the main point is, you have to go through this site https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

# Create sample data
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2022-01-01"), by = "day", length.out = 365),
                 value_A = rnorm(365, 50, 10),
                 value_B = rnorm(365, 75, 15),
                 value_C = rnorm(365, 100, 20))

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(
      HTML(
        "
        /* Add a grey background to the sidebar */
        .col-sm-2 {
          background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
        "
      )
    )
  ),
  titlePanel("Sample Line Charts"),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      2,
      sliderInput(
        "date_range",
        "Date Range:",
        min = min(df$date),
        max = max(df$date),
        value = c(min(df$date),
                  max(df$date))
      )
    ),
    column(
      10,
      fluidRow(
        column(6, plotOutput("plot_A", height = "400px")),
        column(6, plotOutput("plot_B", height = "400px"))
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(12, plotOutput("plot_C", height = "600px"))
      )
    )
  )
)

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]